# while loop to echo variable until empty in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop

Here is what we have in the `$foo` variable:

```
abc bcd cde def
```

We need to echo the first part of the variable ONLY, and do this repeatedly until there's nothing left.

Example:

```
$ magic_while_code_here
I am on abc
I am on bcd
I am on cde
I am on def
```

It would use the beginning word first, then remove it from the variable. Use the beginning word first, etc. until empty, then it quits.

So the variable would be `abc bcd cde def`, then `bcd cde def`, then `cde def`, etc.

We would show what we have tried but we are not sure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use the while loop and cut the parts from the beginning of the string, you can use the `cut` command.

```
foo="abc bcd cde def"

while :
do
  p1=`cut -f1 -d" " <<<"$foo"`
  echo "I am on $p1"
  foo=`cut -f2- -d" " <<<"$foo"`
  if [ "$p1" == "$foo" ]; then
    break
  fi
done
```

This will output:

```
I am on abc
I am on bcd
I am on cde
I am on def
```

Comment: Note that backticks \` are [discouraged](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). The `$( .. )` command substitution is greatly preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the variable consist of sequences of only alphabetic characters separated by space or tabs or newlines, we can (ab-)use the word splitting expansion and just do `printf`:

```
foo="abc bcd cde def"
printf "I am on %s\n" $foo
```

will output:

```
I am on abc
I am on bcd
I am on cde
I am on def
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `read -a` to read the string into an array, then print it:

```
$ foo='abc bcd cde def'
$ read -ra arr <<< "$foo"
$ printf 'I am on %s\n' "${arr[@]}"
I am on abc
I am on bcd
I am on cde
I am on def
```

The `-r` option makes sure backslashes in `$foo` aren't interpreted; `read -a` allows you to have any characters you want in `$foo` and split on whitespace.

---

Alternatively, if you can use awk, you could loop over all fields like this:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {print "I am on", $i}}' <<< "$foo"
```